# Ler dados em uma SQL com colunas de nomes iguais em tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, sql, foreach

Eu preciso recuperar dados de 2 tabelas. A minha ***SQL*** apresentada logo abaixo funciona perfeitamente. O problema é que eu fiz um `foreach` para recuperar os dados da segunda tabela pelo campo `ID` que está conflitando com a primeira tabela já que as duas têm o campo `ID`.

***SQL***

```
$sql = "SELECT tb_faqs.*, tb_paginas.* 
FROM (tb_faqs INNER JOIN tb_paginas) 
WHERE tb_faqs.ID = '$id' 
AND tb_faqs.id_pagina = tb_paginas.ID";

$query = $pdo->query($sql);
$pagina = $query->fetch();
```

Esta ***SQL*** busca todos os dados necessários para das duas tabelas mas eu preciso fazer um `foreach` na segunda tabela para montar um `select` dinâmico a partir dessa consulta. Este é o `foreach`:

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $pagina) {
     echo '<option value="'.$pagina['ID'].'" '.(($pagina['id_pagina'] == $pagina['ID']) ? 'selected="selected"' : "").'>'.$pagina['pagina'].'</option>';
}
```

***Pergunta:*** Quando duas tabelas têm o mesmo ***nome de coluna***, como especificar em qual tabela queremos consultar aquele coluna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere seu SQL para:

```
$sql = "SELECT tb_faqs.*, tb_fags.id as id_fag, tb_paginas.*, tb_paginas.id as id_pagina 
FROM (tb_faqs INNER JOIN tb_paginas) 
WHERE tb_faqs.ID = '$id' 
AND tb_faqs.id_pagina = tb_paginas.ID";
```

E na hora do Foreach() faça: echo $id_fag, echo $id_pagina... 
Não há necessidade de ser exatamente estes nomes, se der conflito, altere, que ele cria um alise (as) para cada ID.

Comment: O echo do ALIAS é alguma coisa parecida com **$faqs['idpag']** dentro do **foreach()** ...